# Can you put hubs in a full-time 4WD vehicle?

Tags: mitsubishi, 4wd, awd, swap

Hi everyone I drive a '95 JDM Mitsubishi RVR and it's full-time 4WD.
I don't know much about 4WD vehicles but my mate drives a '93 JDM Mitsubishi Pajero (Montero for NA and SA people) and he has hubs. And in his car it's part-time 4WD so you disable it and disable the hubs and just drive around in RWD mode. Now I was wondering if I could also put hubs in my car so I can also drive in RWD mode when I don't need 4WD. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything online about hubs in full-time vehicles. Does that mean it's impossible?
Oh and also one more thing my car's manual and my mate's is automatic but I believe it doesn't really make a difference right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most full-time 4WD vehicles, usually called AWD, are primarily front-wheel drives with a transaxle and then a transfer case to a driveshaft that runs the rear axle.  Your JDM Mitsubishi RVR appears to be one of these.

For these vehicles you have 3 differentials, one each at the front and the rear axles and a 3rd one between the front and the rear.  So if you disconnect the power to the front, perhaps with some locking hubs, the differential would then not send any power to the rear due to the way differentials work.  So the vehicle just would not move.

Comment: Got it thanks. But what about if 4WD is RWD-derived? So for example I know a guy who drives a JDM Nissan Stagea (basically Skyline wagon). Base model for these is RWD and it also comes with full time 4WD. How do these work then? Also another example is Subaru they have completely different system right? Also full time 4WD (at least manual models are)

Comment: Perhaps but it's going to depend on the specific vehicle and possibly the options installed on that one.  It's really not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  If you want a 2WD vehicle, then you may be better off just getting one.

Comment: Well it was a theoretical question I'm not really trying to acomplish anything. Just curious